# Accessing in memory data from a Windows Server to an ASP.NET server without a database or file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a C# library that ultimately builds a complex object graph.  To make the object graph, takes about 20 to 30 seconds.  The object graph contains a hierarchy of groups where a user can perform a process on a group that only impacts the children of that group.

i would like to create a web application that sits on top of this object graph.
My desire is:

- A browser client can initialize the loading of the object graph but the object graph is not persisted in a database.
- Multiple clients can visualize the object graph within the browser.
- Multiple clients can modify one of the groups and children and all clients eventually see the changes.

I am experienced using Angular 2+ and ASP.NET Core C#.

My initial thought was to create a windows service to host the in memory object graph instances.  Where i am struggling is how to make the ASP.NET Core server talk to the Windows Service in memory data without using a database or files.

Anyone willing to share some ideas that i can look into?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: There are numerous approaches for "Interprocess Communication" (IPC): Pick your poisons: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx (Memory) Mapped Files and Pipes are teh most commonly used approaches, I think. But any Network communicaiton agaisnt LocalHost would work.

Comment: You can keep the object graph in your web project. Make it a singleton and it won't need to be recreated unless IIS recycles the pool. It's strange to take 20-30 seconds to create an object graph, though. You should review the creation process to see if it can be enhanced.

Comment: You also might greatly underestiamte a DB's ability to deal with BLOBs. Ever since filestream, there is a pretty decent way: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Comment: Have you thought about Redis? https://redis.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using Redis?

Redis is an **in-memory data structure store**, used as a database, cache and message broker. **It supports data structures** such as strings, hashes, lists, sets, sorted sets with range queries, bitmaps, hyperloglogs and geospatial indexes with radius queries.

Redis has **different levels of on-disk persistence**.

Further information can be found [here](https://redis.io/).